# Azure Authentication guideline

Tags: azure, authentication

Azure supports multiple authentication methods including username/password or ssh even AD authentication. Suppose I require ARM template which will setup a new VM , getting docker image from registry server and setting up redis or other required service. Many of these components require authentication in some manner.

Is there is some option may be a key which once authenticated will remove the requirement of authentication again and again?

Comment: Do you mean you want remove the requirement of authentication when you try to login that VM?

Comment: I mean to find a way that once authenticated I dont have to pass authentication creds for other resources or if Azure has a authentication guidlines then it will be good

Comment: Azure SSO can achieve that, but SSO only work for application, not Azure VM or other resources, more information please check my answer, hope that helps:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, it seems you are looking for Azure single sign-on, but this feature works for application, not Azure VM or other Azure resources.

> **Single sign-on** means being able to access all of the applications and
>   resources that you need to do business, by signing in only once using
>   a single user account. Once signed in, you can access all of the
>   applications you need without being required to authenticate (e.g.
>   type a password) a second time.

After we enable this feature, when we use Azure AD account to login windows 10, then we use IE or other browses to access application(SaaS), we will not have to authenticate it again(without username and password).

More information about Azure SSO, please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-appssoaccess-whatis).

But this feature not work for Azure VMs and other resources.
If you want to login VM without username and password, maybe we should deploy our **kerberos** server.

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: Does that work for you? please let me know if you need more help:)